# How does the induced current flow through the coil

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity, conductors, electromagnetic-induction

Take a circuilar coil and a rectangular coil. Change magnetic field through them.
Due to circular symmetry electric field of same magnitude
is induced all over the coil.But in rectangular coil there are different magnitudes of different electric fields induced due to absence of circular symmetry.

## My doubt is-" How electric current flow through such a circularly unsymmetrical coil with different electric field at different places of the coil".*https://photos.app.goo.gl/pM1gxijwY5kVaivr7* and

https://photos.app.goo.gl/1kfK5dNdtpQursP2A

Answer (score 0):

The circular electric field can be resolved along the rectangular wire and hence we have a field along the wire which leads to a current.